# Not able to disable the validation request for asp.net page with parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, richtextbox

I am using the tinyMCE rich text editor in gridview in my page. When I am changing the gridview to edit mode, I'm getting the error "Invalid postback or callback argument. Event validation is enabled". To over come this error, I have added the below code in my web.config file.

Now richtext is working fine for mypage.aspx page. But my problem is that I am passing some parameters into this page and reloading this page like "mypage.aspx?tp=all".  In that case I'm getting the same error. Is there any way I can add below code to work with all parameters.

I have tried as below but loading it self failing.

```
      <location path="mypage.aspx?tp=all">  tried

    <location path="mypage.aspx">
     <system.web>
      <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
      <pages validateRequest="false" />
    </system.web>
    </location>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding it to mypage.aspx directly using @Page directive

```
<%@ Page validateRequest="false" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added my following line to make it work.

```
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
          {
             //added all page load code here
          }
```

and in web config added this:

```
    <location path="mypage.aspx">
       <system.web>
         <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
         <pages validateRequest="false" />
       </system.web>
    </location>
```